# Perfino impact of server becoming unreachable / offline

Tags: perfino

Regarding Perfino from EJ-Technologies...:

Once the Agent is installed against PROD JVMs, what happens if the Perfino server becomes unavailable?

My concern is not that profiling data might be missed, but rather whether PROD would become unstable or unstartable if Perfino died a sudden death and could not be rapidly recovered.

Thanks, Robin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The agent will never become unstable if there is no perfino server. It caches recorded data and transfers it to the perfino server when a connection can be made. Connection attempts are made from time to time and you can see corresponding output on stderr.

After a certain period it will lose cached data to avoid substantial memory overhead to the monitored JVM.